# Grafana installs successfully but interface is missing on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, grafana

*I try to install the grafana and followed the instruction*

```
git clone https://github.com/grafana/grafana.git
cd grafana
brew  install node 
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
grunt build
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Entering [Localhost:8080](http://127.0.0.1:8000) shows the following rather than grafana interface:

[image]

Comment: sorry not griffin, it's grafana

Comment: I attach the picture but it doesn't show here. It only lists the files.

Comment: Did you end up getting it working based on your last comment? Where did you get these instructions? Looking at http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/ I'm using different instructions (though I suppose they could have changed over the last few months).

Comment: brand new to grafana, so ran into this issue as well. For the 3.1 build looks like the default is http://localhost:3000/login
Shows up in the logs after starting the grafana:
INFO[10-31|15:57:10] Server Listening                         logger=server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl=